# Easy question about $H_0^1$ space

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I have some trouble with proper understanding of $H_0^1(0,1)$ space. Consider the following space $$H_D = \{u\in H^1(0,1): u(0) = u(1) = 0\}.$$ What can we say about the connection between $H_D$ and $H^1_0(0,1)$. Is $H_D$ in $H^1_0(0,1)$? In literature stays, that functions in $H_0^1(0,l)$ are interpreted as $$''u = 0\; \text{on}\; \partial\Omega''.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know anything about the [trace operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28Sobolev_space%29)? There is a theorem that says that if $U$ is a bounded domain and $\partial U$ is $C^1$ and $u \in W^{1,p}$, then
$$
u \in W_0^{1,p}(U) \iff Tu=0 \text{ on } \partial U, 
$$
where $T$ is the trace operator. You want $p = 2$ here.

Comment: I have heard about the trace operator. I think, that in my case, since $U = [0,1]$ and $u\in H^1(0,1)$, it means that $H_D = H_0^1(0,1)$. Is it correct?

Comment: @Dina In your case $U = (0,1)$. Elements in $H^1(0,1)$ don't have a value on the boundary (the points 0 and 1) to begin with, but are given the values that they get from the trace operator. Yes, $H_D = H_0^1(0,1)$.

Comment: N.U., thank you! Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

In one-dimensions, Sobolev functions have a well-defined continuous representative. Therefore, they are well-defined at every point of their domain.